# How can I configure the port a Quarkus application runs on?

Tags: quarkus

I would like my Quarkus application to run on a port other than the default. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Quarkus configuration property to be used is `quarkus.http.port` (the default value is 8080).
If this property is set in `application.properties` then that value will be used.

The property can also be overridden at runtime as follows:

When running a Quarkus application in JVM mode you can set the port using the quarkus.http.port System property. 
For example:

```
java -Dquarkus.http.port=8081 -jar example-runner.java
```

The same property applies to GraalVM Native Mode images. 
For example:

```
./example-runner -Dquarkus.http.port=8081
```

Comment: Also if you run this app inside a container remember to add: 
`-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0` to access from outside.

Comment: @HectorVenturaReyes that is true for `0.11.0`, but should not be necessary for newer versions

Comment: @geoand where is the full list of quarkus properties?

Comment: @Tuelho There isn't one yet (but there are plans to create it). You would have to look at the source code of *Config classes, like https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/0.14.0/extensions/undertow/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/undertow/runtime/HttpConfig.java

Comment: And if you need to override the default test port use: `quarkus.http.test-port=8888` I was having issues running tests on windows.

Comment: The following command also works: `mvn -Dquarkus.http.port=8081 quarkus:dev`

Answer (score 5):

To complement geoand’s answer, you can use the same property for `mvn quarkus:dev`. Unfortunately you cannot directly set it in a profile in `~/.m2/settings.xml` to avoid the need to type it each time (for example because [Microk8s binds 8080](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/43)), but you *can* set it via `jvm.args`:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>microk8s-quarkus-dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <jvm.args>-Dquarkus.http.port=8090</jvm.args>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Alternately, you could configure this [in project sources](https://quarkus.io/guides/application-configuration-guide#configuration-profiles):

```sh
echo '%dev.quarkus.http.port=8090' >> src/main/resources/application.properties
```

though this would not be shared across projects, and might be unwanted by other developers of the same project.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<projhome>/resources/application.properties` to configure the port.

For example

```
quarkus.http.port=8080
%dev.quarkus.http.port=8811
%test.quarkus.http.port=7711
%server.quarkus.http.port=6611
```

Here dev, test, and server refer to the profiles.

You can run them as below

`$ mvn compile quarkus:dev` -- port 8811 will be used

`$ mvn -Dquarkus-profile=server compile quarkus:dev` -- port 6611 will be used

Answer (score 0):

To change the default port for a Quarkus application, you would indeed add the following line to your application.properties file:

**quarkus.http.port=8001**

This line instructs Quarkus to use port 8001 instead of the default port 8080 for HTTP communication.