# How to fix the error Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

I've created a quarkus quick start project with

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.13.1:create \
    -DprojectGroupId=com.demo.quarkus \
    -DprojectArtifactId=quarkus-project \
    -DclassName="com.demo.quarkus.HelloResource" \
    -Dpath="/hello"
```

And afterwards when I run:

```
mvn clean package
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentTemplate.doServerStart(UndertowDeploymentTemplate.java:349)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentTemplate.startUndertow(UndertowDeploymentTemplate.java:262)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.UndertowBuildStep$boot9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:96)
    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:236)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.createTestInstance(QuarkusTestExtension.java:301)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassTestDescriptor.java:299)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:281)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:178)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:310)
    at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:193)
    ... 56 more

org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [com.baeldung.quarkus.HelloResourceTest]: Failed to start quarkus

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassTestDescriptor.java:314)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:281)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:96)
    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:236)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.createTestInstance(QuarkusTestExtension.java:301)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassTestDescriptor.java:299)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentTemplate.doServerStart(UndertowDeploymentTemplate.java:349)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentTemplate.startUndertow(UndertowDeploymentTemplate.java:262)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.UndertowBuildStep$boot9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:178)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:310)
    at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:193)
    ... 56 more
```

The origin of the error seems to be coming from

```
@QuarkusTest
public class HelloResourceTest {

    @Test
    public void testHelloEndpoint() {
        given()
                .when().get("/hello/filipe")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("hello"));
    }

}
```

I'm not sure which port it is trying to bind to. I suppose 8080.

Any ideas how to override the default port using the application.properties?

I'm on windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems that besides the normal HTTP port, there is also a default port used during tests. So in order to override the default port used in tests, the following property needs to be overridden:

```
quarkus.http.test-port=8888
```

This will run the rests using port 8888.

The answer for this question pointed me in the right direction:
[How can I configure the port a Quarkus application runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043620/how-can-i-configure-the-port-a-quarkus-application-runs-on)

As well as the comment pointing to 
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/0.14.0/extensions/undertow/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/undertow/runtime/HttpConfig.java

More info here:
https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#controlling-the-test-port

Comment: To build multiple quarkus modules in parallel (for example mvnd), it can be handy to put this on `quarkus.http.test-port=0` to get a free port dynamically. See also https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/28563

Answer (score 2):

It seems to use 8080 by default.

> Quarkus itself is configured via the same mechanism as your application. Quarkus reserves the quarkus. namespace for its own configuration. For example to configure the HTTP server port you can set quarkus.http.port in application.properties.

https://quarkus.io/guides/application-configuration-guide

Comment: The problem was actually due to the http test port used. To override the correct parameter is `quarkus.http.test-port`