# How to configure the port of a Spring Boot app that's natively compiled by GraalVM Native Image from command line?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Spring Boot introduces GraalVM Native Image support with the introduction of the [Spring Graal Native 0.6.0](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/09/spring-graal-native-0-6-0-released) feature. Now if we have a successfully compiled native Spring Boot app, how can we dynamically change the port of an application at startup on the commandline ([as we are used to in JVM mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application))?

This is crucial for deployment scenarios with Docker or cloud providers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we're already used to do this in JVM mode like:

```
java -Dserver.port=8087 -jar spring-boot-graal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

we can do the same with a natively compiled Spring Boot app:

```
./spring-boot-graal -Dserver.port=8087
```

Thanks for [the inspiration from Quarkus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55043637/4964553)! See 100% comprehensible example project here: https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-graalvm